I'm failed to create openstack network
I failed to excute this command openstack network create --share --external --availability-zone-hint nova --provider-physical-network provider --provider-network-type flat public
It will display the message that include ascii app.py 406 line.
We can only remove the compute and build a new one when me see it.
I have configurated the keystone,glance,nova,mysql,rabbitmq and the compute node.
First,I tried to reboot the virtual machine,but failed.
And then,I tried to edit the app.py and write the decode code,Failed again.
